# Discrepancy between table and div width

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I am trying to make th the same width as nested divs. So basically I want the width of the columns to be the same as the div, when the table and the parent div are of the same size.

I have managed to make them nearly the same, but there is still some padding in the table cells that I cannot figure out.

Codesandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wyzz001kyk

html:

```
<div class='header'>
  <div class='one'>One</div>
  <div class='two'>Two</div>
</div>
<table class='table'>
  <th class='one'>One</th>
   <th class='two'>Two</th>
</table>
```

css:

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.one {
  width: 60%;
}

.two {
  width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: use the insert code snippet feature to insert a replica of the problem directly in the question

Comment: flex has a default `flex-basis:auto` which means automatic sizing of the elements - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis.  I've found that the only way it will respect a width is to set both min and max widths to be the value you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly remove the padding from th and td elements:

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.one {
  width: 60%;
}
.two {
  width: 40%;
}
/* this */
.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='header'>
  <div class='one'>One</div>
  <div class='two'>Two</div>
</div>
<table class='table'>
  <th class='one'>One</th>
  <th class='two'>Two</th>
</table>
```